# Android Studio wont update due to conflicts

Tags: android, gradle

Below is a picture of the errors:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od240.png

I have tried so much...

1. renaming the Gradle folder and trying to update
2. renaming android SDK folder and trying to update
3. replacing said files with the original from seperte downloads

I'm just so so sooooo stuck. I've been trying for 2 days. I have the issue that I cannot build anything in Gradle as my Android Studio must update first, but Gradle is the reason I cannot update.

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: uninstall. reinstall.